# How to add zero to mysql (varchar) field, but only to ones that start with different than zero number. Lenght of phone numbers vary

Tags: mysql

I have imported a few thousand records in my existing CRM database from CSV and apparently all leading zeroes in the phone numbers column have disappeared. In searching for an answer all other questions I could find were about fixed length of the string. but my phone numbers vary in length. The ones that need their leading zeroes back are the ones starting with different than zero number. The old records (prior to my CSV import) are fine and I do not need another zero to go in front of them.
Please bare in mind I am not a programmer and this is all very difficult to me - even to explain.

I've tried to export the database table via phpmyadmin in CSV and sort the problem out in LibreOffice and then put it back (import) ...but there are records `NULL` that are not in quotes `""` when exported and when I save the file in LibreOffice all fields are in quotes including the NULL ones. So I guess this will not work. It is a production environment. The table in question is the "contacts" table for a SugarCRM CE database. The field is `varchar(100)`. So to summarize my question is: is there a function that I can put in phpmyadmin or in the terminal (i have root access), that will identify the records in this particular table (contacts), that start with number different than zero and ad one zero in front?
I know that I am expected to show a code that I've tried and to give some feedback what the result is, but I just can't. Sorry. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: mysql server] [image: fields]

Comment: The best fix here is to import your phone number as _text_, not as numbers, which appears to be what you have already done.  If you want a patch to left pad your text phone number with zeroes, we can help with that, but we would need to see some sample data.

Comment: If the 0 is actually chacode 0 then it will be interpreted as a null terminator which is used to mark the end of a string, you need to ensure that when you want a 0 as a number then you convert it to an ASCII code by adding on 0x30 (hex) or 48 decimal.

Comment: Incidentally, never use '-' within a table/column identifier. It can have catastrophic consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET phone = CONCAT("0", phone) WHERE LEFT(phone, 1) <> "0";
```

You can first run SELECT with the same condition to see if it correctly return the rows that have phone numbers that lost their leading zeros

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mean:
SELECT table1 SET phone = CONCAT("0", phone) WHERE LEFT(phone, 1) <> "0";

Comment: You cannot have both SELECT and UPDATE. I mean SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE LEFT(phone, 1) <> "0"

Comment: You can see how lost I am in this :)

SELECT * FROM `contacts-test` WHERE LEFT(phone_home, 1) <> "0"
This seams to work and it returns all the numbers starting with number other than zero. The only "problem" is that it returns empty rows as well and if I execute UPDATE contacts-test SET phone_home = CONCAT("0", phone_home) WHERE LEFT(phone_home, 1) <> "0"; it will probably insert 0 to every empty record. It is not the end of the world as it will fix my problem with the missing zeros but just wondering if there a way to exclude the empty records?
Big thanks Nedret!

Comment: You can just add an extra condition then: AND phone <> "".  You can first run the SELECT and if all is OK run the UPDATE

Comment: Thank you Nedret! It worked like a charm! Here is the final query: UPDATE `contacts` SET phone_work = CONCAT("0", phone_work) WHERE LEFT(phone_work, 1) > "0" AND LEFT(phone_work, 1) <> "0" AND phone_work IS NOT NULL AND phone_work <> "BLOCKED" AND phone_work <> "anonymous" ;